# How to edit the Django Admin User social auths listing page?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-socialauth

I am having trouble finding where this admin file exists so I can add an extra field. I think it's auto-magically created upon setup.

I want to add a date field, specifically, to the listing page (shown below), perhaps after the UID field so I can know when the user auth was created.

[screenshot of django user social auths listing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIqgo.png)

Comment: Since the issue that you are trying to solve is a high level one, I'd suggest you going through the following tutorial first. This should let you understand better how Django works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's what I've tried using **Django-allauth** and I think it somehow works the same with django-socialauth. Just get the gist of the idea and work it to your code

Extend first the **SocialAccountAdmin** in any of your admin.py files, better if in a specific app like "**user**", "**home**", or whatever you prefer.

***admin.py***

```
from allauth.socialaccount.admin import SocialAccountAdmin
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

class MySocialAccount(SocialAccountAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'uid', 'provider', 'date_joined')  # I haven't tried just adding a certain list to the list_display, for the meantime add all necessary fields just like how socialauth did


admin.site.unregister(SocialAccount)  # Need to unregister the default socialaccount admin
admin.site.register(SocialAccount, MySocialAccount)  # Then register it back with the custom made admin
```

There may be perhaps a better way to do this but this did the work.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be interesting to just add a field to your model ? Adding a DateField for your creation date. Probably you need to understand learn more with : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/